# Get dict inside a list with value without for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dict:

```
data_flights = {
  "prices": [
    { "city": "Paris", "iataCode": "AAA", "lowestPrice": 54, "id": 2 },
    { "city": "Berlin", "iataCode": "BBB", "lowestPrice": 42, "id": 3 },
    { "city": "Tokyo", "iataCode": "CCC", "lowestPrice": 485, "id": 4 },
    { "city": "Sydney", "iataCode": "DDD", "lowestPrice": 551, "id": 5 },
  ],
  "date": "31/03/2022"
}
```

Can I acess a dict using a key value from one of the dics,  without using for loop?
something like this:

```
data_flights["prices"]["city" == "Berlin"]
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example that shows what you are looking to achieve with a for loop? Are you looking to only select cities that `== "berlin"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by either using a comprehension or the `filter` built in.

**comprehension:**

```
[e for e in d['prices'] if e['city'] == 'Berlin']
```

**filter:**

```
list(filter(lambda e: e['city'] == 'Berlin', d['prices']))
```

**Both would result in:**

```
[{'city': 'Berlin', 'iataCode': 'BBB', 'lowestPrice': 42, 'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```py
x = [a for a in data_flights["prices"] if a["city"] == "Berlin"]
```

```py
>>> x
[{'city': 'Berlin', 'iataCode': 'BBB', 'lowestPrice': 42, 'id': 3}]
```